.NET MAUI Blazor resource locations
What's the best practices to insert own backgrounds or images for application customizing when i am aiming to release Android APK package.
Because it seems that Blazor .NET MAUI Hybrid (Android) is very janky with images for customizing application backgrounds etc styling. Android version crashes easily if image isn't available or wrong location in solution.
I have tried use background in 'root / index.html' via CSS in body tag, but images doesn't show up and then app crashes in device.

You can put it in the wwwroot folder. Such as: wwwroot\images\background.jpg
And then set it as the html's background image in the wwwroot\css\app.css:
html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color:transparent
}
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

And the result:

